# How to dynamically populate Google Chart with AJAX query, getting DOM exception 8

Tags: java, ajax, json, google-visualization, playframework-1.x

I have a controller that returns (well) formatted JSON in the format that Google Charts expects.  I can view the output by navigating to `http://localhost:9000/manager/echoVariables` and the OP is as follows: `[["foo",3],["foo",3]]`

I want to do a AJAX call and am not able to pass this JSON to Google Charts. I can confirm that the JSON is being received, I verified in Chrome's Browser Inspector's Network Tab.

But I am getting a `DOM Exception 8` on my way to passing this JSON string to Google Charts.

This is the view that is creating the graphs:

```
#{extends 'main.html' /} #{set title:'Home' /} #{set 'moreScripts'}
#{/set}
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//$.get()
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#result").html();
    $.get(
        '/manager/echoVariables',
        {var1: "foo", var2: 5},
        function(responseText){
            $("#result").html(responseText);
        },
        "json"
    );
});


</script>

<body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

How do I make the piechart show my values, instead of the ones that are given in the snippet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two problems with your code.  First, you are using jQuery's `html()` function on your `#result` div, but you're passing a javascript object instead of a string like the function expects.  If you do just want to see the data, you'd change that to something like

```
$.get(
    '/manager/echoVariables',
    {var1: "foo", var2: 5},
    function(responseText){
        $("#result").html(JSON.stringify(responseText));
    },
    "json"
);
```

The other problem, of course, is that you're not actually passing the result data to the google chart API.  To do that, you'll need to call `chart.draw` using data you got back from your AJAX call instead of the data from the example.

Comment: Yes Jeff, I was able to do it. JS is not my forte, and I was wondering if you would help me clean it up?